# Count unique occurrence of a regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a [maillog](http://1drv.ms/1v7oFVV) of a server and I want to count how many e-mails each users sends per each hour.

At the moment I removed every information that I do not need, but I can not make it count how many emails each unique user sends.

What I wrote so far is :

```
 awk '{print $3, $7;}' ./maillog | sed '/from/!d' | sed 's/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] /:00 /g' | sed 's/from=<//g' | egrep '[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(org|net|com)' | uniq -c > output.txt
```

The main problem is that (I believe) that I find the same user multiple times in the same hour (which I do not want).

[Here](http://1drv.ms/1AwMMzQ) is what I need to get. Be aware that what I need to get is just an example, is not the correct output that I should have. If you execute the script that I wrote on the file that I gave you, you will obtain user25 2 times in the same hour which does not satisfy the requirements.

Here is a sample of the output as someone suggested (is very long) :

```
Jan 16 08:33:04 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[3539]: q5c1SrFqkAZq9b: Milter: connect to filters
Jan 16 08:33:06 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[3539]: q5c1SrFqkAZq9b: from=<user1@dont-cross-the-memes.example.com>, size=38065260, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<gnDSaYSEaP4Yk/.F0EhYbIYcihGO8Vd.dont-cross-the-memes.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=proton.dont-cross-the-memes.example.com [192.168.98.234]
Jan 16 08:33:06 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[7734]: qqGjhufuNY5UJ: Milter: connect to filters
Jan 16 08:33:07 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[8780]: qkwEbHuoJi40Lj: Milter: connect to filters
Jan 16 08:33:07 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[8780]: qkwEbHuoJi40Lj: from=<user25@knurledwidgets.example.org>, size=36412443, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<w/7AIsHSy6.gkNTPlyyE55u.knurledwidgets.example.org>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=mail.knurledwidgets.example.org [10.0.0.20]
Jan 16 08:33:08 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[7734]: qqGjhufuNY5UJ: from=<user6@stellar-patrol.example.com>, size=33411319, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<il/5SxUES9XwRhX.KfO6ywkQROALbnz.stellar-patrol.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=feinstein.stellar-patrol.example.com [192.168.73.3]
Jan 16 08:33:09 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[3539]: q5c1SrFqkAZq9b: Milter accept: message
Jan 16 08:33:09 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[8780]: qkwEbHuoJi40Lj: Milter accept: message
Jan 16 08:33:10 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[7734]: qqGjhufuNY5UJ: Milter accept: message
Jan 16 08:33:12 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[1618]: qhgKT0cN80gSX: Milter: connect to filters
Jan 16 08:33:13 mail.knurledwidgets.example.org sendmail[1618]: qhgKT0cN80gSX: from=<user25@knurledwidgets.example.org>, size=780642, class=-30, nrcpts=1, msgid=<hX49btAurMDDZlhWo.5RpGEJxQQilElvDgRpc3sw.knurledwidgets.example.org>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v6, relay=mail.knurledwidgets.example.org [10.0.0.20]
```

And here is a sample of the output :

```
1 08:00 user10@yuhoo.example.com
1 08:00 user19@knurledwidgets.example.org
1 08:00 user1@beshonk.example.com
5 08:00 user27@knurledwidgets.example.org
1 09:00 user12@knurledwidgets.example.org
1 09:00 user17@knurledwidgets.example.org
1 09:00 user26@knurledwidgets.example.org
7 09:00 user27@knurledwidgets.example.org
2 09:00 user33@knurledwidgets.example.org
1 09:00 user42@knurledwidgets.example.org
```

Please also explain the answer that you gave because the aim is to learn not do the exercise.

Thank you for your time

Comment: It would be useful to include a small sample of your input and desired output in the question itself.

Comment: I added the samples, sadly the formating of the input is messed up, basically each line start with Jan (for clarification).

Comment: I assume that is a sample of **desired output?**

Comment: Sadly it isn't, we were not provided with the desired output, it was given just so we can get a feeling of the desired one.

Comment: _Sadly it isn't_...well make one for us then!

Comment: You really need to read documentation more carefully. Wikipedia on uniq has the answer to your question, and the man page of uniq clearly says: *Discard all but one of **successive** identical lines*

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out ! I will pay more attention next time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `sort` before `uniq` will give you the counts:

```
awk '{print $3, $7;}' ./maillog | sed '/from/!d' | sed 's/:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] /:00 /g' | sed 's/from=<//g' | egrep '[a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(org|net|com)' | sort | uniq -c`

  1 08:00 user1@dont-cross-the-memes.example.com>,
  2 08:00 user25@knurledwidgets.example.org>,
  1 08:00 user6@stellar-patrol.example.com>,
```

See `uniq --help`:

> Note: `uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.
>   You may want to sort the input first, or use `sort -u` without `uniq`.
>   Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by `LC_COLLATE`.

Comment: Can you please explain why ? It has something to do with uniq ? Thanks !

Comment: The documentation of uniq should state that only _consecutive_ lines are counted, and that sorting may be necessary to yield the desired result...